# bypass twitter funcaptcha

Tags: python, selenium, captcha, twitter

У меня проблема с обходом Arkoselabs Funcaptcha используя senelium на странице Twitter. Я не могу отправить токен, потому что нет кнопки submit или формы чтобы сабмитить ее. Когда я пытаюсь вставить токен и просто нажимать случайные картинки, я получаю ошибку - неверный ответ. Я также пытался решать капчу, получая изображение и инструкции, отправляя запрос с этим куда-то вроде 2captcha и нажимая на правильные изображения. Раньше это работало, но теперь появилась капча нового типа со стрелочками (нужно выбрать правильную картинку). Когда я сделал то же самое, я просто получил неправильный ответ от 2captcha. Что можно придумать?

Также пробовал расширения от 2captcha, anycaptcha, anticaptcha. Ни одно не работает в твиттере даже без селениума.